# Cant login to the laptop (windows 10 ) with domain users

Tags: windows-10, login, login-screen

at our company, we have several laptops, that for no apparent reason stopped to allow all the users who are not admins in AD to log in. When you try to log in to one of those laptops it goes to a loading screen and just never enters the user profile. Can anyone tell me what I should look for to resolve this issue? thank you

Comment: Sounds like a problem on the domain controller not being able to download the roaming profile.

Comment: You should contact your IT Administrator for assistance with this problem.  As a non-Administrator you will be unable to solve the problem.

Comment: Look at the event log for clues.

Comment: @Ramhound, unfortunately, I am the IT administrator

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator we have already searched at the event viewer, tried to log in with another non-administrative account, log in through the safe mode, and a bunch of other stuff. the thing is, it is only possible to log in to that machine with admin acc, and normal users ( even the ones who already have logged in to the machine before ) cant do that for some reason .

Comment: These details belong in your question.

Comment: @EvgenySdvizhkov - Try creating a new local Administrator on the domain controller.  If that works then add them to the domain Administrator group, see if that works, rinse and repeat with a new domain user.